# How do I get this code to work on google sites?

Tags: javascript, google-sites

I have this code:

```
var links = [cant put links in yet]  var visited = [];

var button = document.getElementById('btn');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {

    if (visited.length == links.length) {
        alert('You visited all the links');
        return;
    }

    var random, url;

    do {
        random  = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        url = links[random];        
    } while (contains(visited, url));
    alert('Opening: ' + url + ' with #' + random);
    visited.push(url);   

    var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
    win.focus(); });

function contains(array, value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == value) return true;
    }
    return false; 
}
```

and I need to combine it together and put it on to a google site. I tried combing it all with       tags in an html box, but all that does is create my button. It doesn't run the script and open the links... Will this code not work on google sites or am I doing it wrong?

[FULL CODE w/html and css](http://jsfiddle.net/pnP4D/10/)

Answer (score 0):

On the Html Box , you can't.
You can use this code with App Engine or use Google App SCript.

you can see an example here : http://tutorialzine.com/2011/01/google-appengine-series/